# why the factory is not able to access inside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have created notification factory and pass inside controller,Inside controller when assign the factory to the scope getting error.

**alertsManager**

```
 MyApp.factory('alertsManager', function() {
                return {
                    alerts: {},
                    addAlert: function(message, type) {
                        this.alerts[type] = this.alerts[type] || [];
                        this.alerts[type].push(message);
                    },
                    clearAlerts: function() {
                        for(var x in this.alerts) {
                       delete this.alerts[x];
                    }
                    }
                };
            });



  var LoginController = function($scope,$rootScope,alerts,alertsManager)
        {
        $scope.alerts = alertsManager.alerts;
        // getting error.
        **angular.js:11594 TypeError: Cannot read property 'alerts' of undefined**
        }

        LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope','alerts','alertsManager'];


       **why factory not able to access inside controller.*
```

Comment: You are injecting 4 using $inject. But, 3 in function `LoginController ` . And remove the ' in function.

Comment: Do you have `alerts` factory?

Comment: yes ,same thing for all the factory , i am not able to access the factory function inside controller.

Comment: Make a fiddle or show more code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below .

**code:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('alertsManager', function() {
  return {
    alerts: {'alert':"i'm from factory service"},
    addAlert: function() { //code },
    clearAlerts: function() { //code }
  }
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','alertsManager', function($scope, alertsManager) {
  $scope.test = alertsManager.alerts.alert;
}]);
```

**Note :** Inject ***factory service*** into Controller

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/8798/)** .

Answer (score 0):

No need to inject 'alerts' as a dependency in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ..very stupid question .. Are you sure Do you include these files in Index.html?

like this:

```
 <script src="app/services/alertsManager.js"></script>
```